# Days Formatting in SAS

Tags: date, datetime, sas, date-format

I have a set of data where I want to manipulate using SAS: Here is my code but it seems that the date format is problematic:

```
/*DATA:
3241 F 100287012
    13431043321110310022
5673 M 211178124
    11031002231134310433
4702 M 170780025
    31134310433211103100
2496 F 030979013
    22311542102231152111
6543 M 090885124
    03100343104332111031 */
/*
1st Row.
Input ID 4. Gender $ Birthdate 6. Race 1. Marital 1. Status_and_Education 1. @@;*/


Data Survey;
    Infile "/folders/myfolders/surveydata.txt";
    Input ID 4. Gender $ Birthdate 6. Race 1. Marital 1. Status_and_Education 1. @@;
    Input / Reponse_1 5. Reponse_2 1. Reponse_3 1. Reponse_4 1. Reponse_5 1.
            Reponse_6 1. Reponse_7 1. Reponse_8 1. Reponse_9 1. Reponse_10 1.
            Reponse_11 1. Reponse_12 1. Reponse_13 1. Reponse_14 1. Reponse_15 1.
            Reponse_16 1. Reponse_17 1. Reponse_18 1. Reponse_19 1. Reponse_20 @;
    format Birthdate ddmmyy8.;
run;

proc print data=Survey;
    format Birthdate DDMMYY.;
run;
```

this is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't read the variable BIRTHDATE as a date, you read it as a regular number. So for the first line of your data I see this string `100287` which you read as the number 100,287.  Since today is day number 21,169 that value represents a day that is over 79,000 days or over 216 years from now.

Try code like this instead.  Note I like to use YMD order for dates instead of MDY or DMY order to avoid confusion when working with people/data from different regions of the world.

```
data Survey;
  infile "/folders/myfolders/surveydata.txt";
  input ID 4. +1 Gender $1. +1 Birthdate ddmmyy6. Race 1.
        Marital 1. Status_and_Education 1. 
      / Response_1 5. (Response_2-Response_20) (1.)
  ;
  format Birthdate yymmdd10.;
run;
```